# Which storage should be used to store master data in azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I want to store my master data in some azure storage so that same can be accessed in all my applications deployed in azure. The data need to be fetched large number of times and will be updated rarely.

Currently this data is stored in SQL Server and is accessed by Applications in Data centers (not on azure).

I have thought of SQL, Redis and CosmosDB as of now but still not sure of which one to be used.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is very broad and there can be many answers. What I would suggest you do is narrow down your focus and come up with concrete problems you're facing.

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to store configuration data, you can use [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/). It can act as a central configuration point that stores connection string to your database(s), container(s), encryption keys etc.

When I had to store larger chunks of data, I found SQL to be the most efficient and most easy to use. Of course, this depends on what operations you have to run against the master data.

Comment: Key vault is not suitable to be a database store. And just suggesting using SQL, without knowing anything about what's being stored, is just as good as throwing out any other storage option. Is the op storing binary images? searchable metadata? MBs/GB/TB/PB? Reporting needs? Integration with other systems?